# load files with string formatting

Tags: python, string, loops, dataset, load

I want to load a set of files in python and I want to load them one by one, then read the data. But , I do not know how to use string formatting?!
This is one file which I load in this way:

data = Dataset('ndb.fragment_1')

I am looking for some ways to load the others (like, ndb.fragment_2, ndb.fragment_3 , ...), all in one python script. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Use the available formatting options in StackOverflow editor when posting code snippets in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what Dataset is, but assuming it opens the file and reads the data you can do this:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("ndb.fragment_*")
data = []
for file in files:
    data.append(Dataset(file))
```

If you need more help, it might be useful to post a bit more description of your issue.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention the format: they are binary data and then I use netCDF4 to read the data in the form of numbers to use in my calculation. your answer was really helpful in reading the data. Later on I modified the second line in your answer to also sort them :

files = sorted(glob.glob("ndb.fragment_*"), key=lambda n: int(re.findall(r'\d+', n)[0]))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the glob library. like this :

```
In [2]: from glob import glob

In [3]: glob('*.csv')

Out[3]: ['3.csv', '2.csv', '4.csv', '1.csv']
```

after this, you can iterate over this list and read all the files one by one.